# Retrofit: Unable to create converter for class

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to get data from an API using retrofit in Kotlin. The data is structured in the following way

```
{
  "key1": Int,
  "key2": String,
  "list": [
  {
    "subkey1": Int,
    "subkey2": String
  },
  {
    "subkey1": Int,
    "subkey2": String
  },
  ...
  ]
}
```

so I wanted to have two dataclasses; one for the individual entries

```
@Serializable
data class SubClass(
  val subkey1: Int,
  val subkey2: String,
)
```

and one for the parent containing a list of the individual entries

```
@Serializable
data class ParentClass(
  val key1: Int,
  val key2: String,
  val list: List<SubClass>
)
```

My retrofit builder looks like this:

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

and the API is called from using the `call` function:

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET()
    suspend fun call() : ParentClass
}

object Api {
    val retrofitService : ApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

(for this I followed the [codelab by Google](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-getting-data-internet)

Gradle build works fine, but when I call the function `call` the app crashes with the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.app, PID: 9880
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.example.app.Parentclass
                                                                                                        for method ApiService.search
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I also tried to add the @SerialName tag to every val but this didn't help.